# PHP Wrap ALL fields in quotes fputcsv()

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, fputcsv

I'm relatively new to PHP so please bear with me.

my code currently looks like this:

```
<?php

require("database.php");

$localfile = "FileName.csv";
$fp = fopen($localfile, "w"); 
$enclosure = '"';
$delimiter = ',';

if(!$link)
{
    echo "DB Connection ERROR";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM A_Table WHERE Stuff";

$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        fputcsv($fp,$row,$delimiter,$enclosure);
    }

fclose($localfile);

?>
```

This works as expected, however, the client requires ALL fields to be wrapped in quotations, not just those containing spaces. I've seen a lot of solutions online but they all seem overly complicated or seem to suggest that I should edit the CSV once it's exported.

If this is the case then I shall persevere but does anybody have a relatively simple solution for my dilemma?

**Example**

Normal code will output: `col1,col2,"col 3",col4`

I would like to output: `"col1","col2","col 3","col4"`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for inspiration. You can replace the `$row` argument to `fputcsv()` with the `array_map()` line you see in my demo here:

```
<?php

// Sample values
$unquoted = ['these', 'are', 'some', 'unquoted', 'example', 'values'];

// One-liner to quote every array element and output to new array.
$quoted = array_map(function ($element) { return "\"$element\""; }, $unquoted);

var_dump($quoted);
/*
Output:
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) ""these""
  [1]=>
  string(5) ""are""
  [2]=>
  string(6) ""some""
  [3]=>
  string(10) ""unquoted""
  [4]=>
  string(9) ""example""
  [5]=>
  string(8) ""values""
}
*/
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help... I'm nearly there! I think, I now have $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$quoted = array_map(function ($element) { return "\"$element\""; }, $row);

fputcsv($fp,$quoted);

}   This outputs the fields wrapped in quotes... but 3 either side so """col1""", do you know what my next step is?

Comment: Try replacing `return "\"$element\""` with `return '"' . trim($element, '"') . '"'`.

Comment: I think this is the right direction, but it's returning the same thing. It's as though it's wrapping the quotations in quotes. What I mean by this is if I write `return ' '.$element,' ' `  I get back " col1 ".

Comment: If some of your fields are already double-quoted, then you can omit the 'enclosure' argument, combined with my `array_map()` one-liner (the one including `trim()`).

Comment: A Solution has been found! Your approach was great and I'd like to thank you very much because you've introduced me to the possibilities of an array_map, however, the solution was to use `fwrite` instead of `fputcsv` full solution `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        fwrite($fp, '"'.implode('","', $row) . "\"\r\n");
    }`

Comment: Good job. There are many ways to write out a single line with a simple delimiter and some quoting. If you found my answer helpful, then please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the accepted answer :).